# How can I handle the directory of files inside Codespaces , Especial css path in html page?

Tags: html, css, directory, codespaces

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
       <title>Israa's Charity</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="header">
          <h2>Israa's Charity</h2>
          <div class="img"><img alt="kheer" src="/images/img0.jpg"></div>
          <ul>
             <li><a class="active" href="/"><b>Home</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="/category"><b>Category</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="/login"><b>Login In</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="/register"><b>Register</b></a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="p0">
           <p>Volunteering gives people an opportunity to change the lives of those they do and the lives of those around them, as it gives them the satisfaction of playing some roles in someone else’s life,</p>
           <p>and helping people who may not be able to help themselves, and it can be said that volunteering is a way to give back to the community in which we live, as well as strengthening important social skills,</p>
           <p>and gaining experience in a field that is valuable at the same time. That is, volunteering has many benefits, including that it is a powerful way to gain some references that fit the life path of those who do it,</p>
           <p> and volunteer work is for some people to do a number of jobs without getting paid for it, but in return for it they gain experience in very competitive fields such as television .</p>
       </div>
       <div class="img_p0">
           <img src="/images/cover0.jpg" alt="p0">
```

`When I load this html page, the images don't appear , Seems just
small icons in the place of images.

Aboveis a small shot of the html code.
The error is that "this page failed to load a stylesheet from a
URL".
All I get " there is a mistake with the path of (
href="/css/style.css")
I have a main folder named charity.
The directory like that:

1. charity

   - templates

     - layout.html
   - css

     - style.css
   - images

     - img0.jpg
     - cover0.jpg

Refused to apply style from 'https://glowing-space-barnacle-45wpq76vj69cqgrp-5000.app.github.dev/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.